# Rails routing for top-level inside a scope and resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my Rails application I have the following controllers:

```
/controllers/journeys_controller.rb
/controllers/policies/journeys_controller.rb
/controllers/policies/drivers/journeys_controller.rb
/controllers/policies/vehicles/journeys_controller.rb
```

And the code for them is as:

```
class JourneysController < ApplicationController

    def custom_1; end

    def custom_2; end

end

module Policies
    class JourneysController < ApplicationController

        def index; end

        def show; end

    end
end

module Policies
    module Drivers
        class JourneysController < ApplicationController

            def index; end

            def show; end

        end
    end
end

module Policies
    module Vehicles
        class JourneysController < ApplicationController

            def index; end

            def show; end

        end
    end
end
```

So as you can see I have methods to list and show journeys for policies, drivers, and vehicles. And then I have custom methods for a journey at a top-level journeys controller.

The routes I have so far are:

```
resources :policies, only: %i[index show] do
  scope module: :policies do
    resources :journeys, only: %i[index show] do
      get 'custom_1' => 'journeys#custom_1'
      get 'custom_2' => 'journeys#custom_2'
    end
    scope module: :drivers do
      resources :journeys, only: %i[index show] do
        get 'custom_1' => 'journeys#custom_1'
        get 'custom_2' => 'journeys#custom_2'
      end
    end
    scope module: :vehicles do
      resources :journeys, only: %i[index show] do
        get 'custom_1' => 'journeys#custom_1'
        get 'custom_2' => 'journeys#custom_2'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However those custom routes are not pointing at the top-level controller:

[image]

[image]

They are in fact pointing at their parent scope (which makes sense). But in my case I want to point those custom methods at the top-level. How can I make those routes point to a different controller but keep them nested so that the URLs stay in tact.

Comment: I know it's not perfect, but what you think about `match`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match

Comment: @MichaelArkhipov Can you show an example of what you are thinking?

Comment: This question does not make sense, the routes you are declaring in each scope block are just clobbering each other since they have the same path. What is the desired output from `rake routes`?

Comment: If you want an example of this guess for example what controller `GET /policies/1/journeys/2/custom_1` will route to.

Comment: @max I want `/policies/:policy_id/drivers/:driver_id/journeys/:journey_id/custom_1(.:format)` to point to `journeys#custom_1`.

Comment: And the same for the other custom methods. They should point to the controller above the modules. But I have nested them so that the URLs are nested as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Resource takes an optional hash where you can specify the controller so

```
resource : journeys do
# code
end
```

would be written as

```
resource : journeys, controller :journeys, module: nil do
 # code
end
```

Being in a module you must get outside it specifying `nil`.

Comment: That's not going to work as some of the methods for that resource are inside the module and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

First off this is just a plain bad idea since you should not be nesting more than [one level deep](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). If you still are intent on doing this you would declare the routes like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :policies, only: %i[index show] do
    # declare anything "top-level" here
    get :top_level_custom_action

    scope module: :policies do
      resources :journeys, only: %i[index show] do
        get :custom_1
        get :custom_2
      end

      resources :drivers, only: [] do
        resources :journeys, module: :drivers, only: %i[index show] do
          get :custom_1
          get :custom_2
        end
      end

      resources :vehicles, only: [] do
        resources :journeys, module: :vehicles, only: %i[index show] do
          get :custom_1
          get :custom_2
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # if you want to create a seperate unested route then declare it in its own 
  # resources block
  resources :journeys, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

But nesting that deep and providing show routes for nested resources is an anti-pattern since each resource has a unique id and can accessed directly without the parent resource. For example `GET policies/1/drivers/2/journeys` will point to the exact same resource as `GET /drivers/2/journeys`.

A better solution with limited nesting would be:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :journeys, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  resources :policies, only: %i[index show] do
    resources :journeys, module: :policies, only: %i[index show] do
      get :custom_1
      get :custom_2
    end
  end

  resources :drivers do
    resources :journeys, scope: :drivers, only: %i[index]
  end

  resources :vehicles do
    resources :journeys, scope: :vehicles, only: %i[index]
  end
end
```

Comment: "each resource has a unique id and can accessed directly without the parent resource" in our application this isn't true. We don't use ActiveRecord and instead need each part of the params from the nested route to access the resource in question.

Comment: In your first example the router for the nested custom routes is still pointing at: `policies/vehicles/journeys#custom_1` when I want it to point to `journeys#custom_1`.

Comment: In short is there no way to get those `get :custom_1` to point to a different controller? Or is the only solution to move the logic into a concern and then have all custom methods use that?

Comment: If you want the custom route to point to journeys#custom_1 then place it in the un-nested call to `resources :journeys` on the bottom.

Comment: But I think you're really not grasping the concepts here and mixing up nested resources which is a REST concept and module nesting which is a ruby language feature and code organisation tool.

Comment: I understand the concept. What were trying to avoid is having lots of lines of routes. As we need the nested URL structure and we have different request params depending on the level. But it sounds like we will have to add a custom match for each URL we need to achieve what we want.